# How to Flutter Markdown Image Provider?

Tags: flutter, image, github, svg, markdown

### In my markdown return

```
[![Build & Release](https://github.com/aelayyuu/****/actions/workflows/action.yml/badge.svg)](https://github.com/aelayyuu/****/actions/workflows/action.yml)
```

### Error is

```
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404,
https://github.com/aelayyuu/****/actions/workflows/action.yml/badge.svg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:97:9)
<asynchronous suspension>

Image provider:
  NetworkImage("https://github.com/aelayyuu/****/actions/workflows/action.yml/badge.svg",
  scale: 1.0)
Image key:
  NetworkImage("https://github.com/aelayyuu/****/actions/workflows/action.yml/badge.svg",
  scale: 1.0)
```

### My code is using markdown: ^5.0.0, flutter_svg: ^1.1.1+1 and flutter_markdown: ^0.6.10+2

```
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:markdown/markdown.dart' as md;

Markdown(
                  controller: controller,
                  selectable: true,
                  data: aboutMD,
                  // imageBuilder: imageBuilder(aboutMD),
                  extensionSet: md.ExtensionSet(
                    md.ExtensionSet.gitHubFlavored.blockSyntaxes,
                    [
                      md.EmojiSyntax(),
                      ...md.ExtensionSet.gitHubFlavored.inlineSyntaxes,
                      md.ImageSyntax(),...md.ExtensionSet.gitHubFlavored.inlineSyntaxes
                    ],
                    
                  ),
                )
```

How to show image such as svg, png, jpg in flutter markdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

> Url lunch

```dart
Future<void> _onTapLink(String text, String? href, String title) async {
    if (href == null) return;
    final Uri url = Uri.parse(href);
    if (!await launchUrl(
      url,
      mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
    )) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Wrong address: $href'),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

> Image showing

```dart
import 'package:markdown/markdown.dart' as md;

Markdown(
    selectable: true,
    data: data,
    onTapLink: onTapLink,
    extensionSet: md.ExtensionSet(
      /*blockSyntaxes=*/ md.ExtensionSet.gitHubFlavored.blockSyntaxes,
      /*inlineSyntaxes=*/ md.ExtensionSet.gitHubFlavored.inlineSyntaxes,
    ),
  );
```